# Qt delete works with Valgrind but not normal execution

Tags: c++, qt, valgrind, delete-operator

I'm checking for memory leaks in my Qt program using QtCreator and Valgrind. I am deleting a few entries in a QHash in my destructor like this:

```
QHash<QString, QVariant*> m_Hash;

/**
 * @brief
 * Destruct a Foo Class instance
 */
Foo ::~Foo ()
{

    // Do Cleanup here

    // Delete hash leftovers
    foreach( QString key, m_Hash.keys() )
    {

        qDebug() << "Deleting an entry..";

        // Delete the hash item
        delete m_Hash.take(key);

    }

}
```

If I debug with Valgrind this code is fine and deletes the contents when the destructor is called:

```
>> Deleting an entry.. 
>> Deleting an entry..
```

If I launch with GDB within QtCreator, launch without GDB from QtCreator, or just run my Qt App from the command line I get Segmentation Faults!

```
Signal name : 
SIGSEGV
Signal meaning : 
Segmentation fault
```

If I commend out the 'delete' line then I can run my app just fine using any method but I do leak memory.

What gives? Does valgrind introduce some sort of delay that allows my destructor to work? How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you give us a code example adding new items into the hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not modify the container you iterate over with foreach. Use iterators instead. Correct code using method [`iterator QHash::erase ( iterator pos )`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qhash.html#erase):

```
 QMap<QString, QVariant* >::iterator it = m_Hash.begin();
 // auto it = m_Hash.begin(); // in C++11
 while (it != m_Hash.end()) {
     delete it.value();
     it = m_Hash.erase(it);
 }
```

Also, any particular reason why you are storing QVariant pointers, instead of values? QVariant is usually suitable for keeping as value, since most data you'd store in QVariant is either implicitly shared, or small.

Answer (score 4):

hyde's answer is correct; however, the simplest possible way to clear your particular hash is as follows:

```
#include <QtAlgorithms>

Foo::~Foo()
{
   qDeleteAll(m_Hash);
   m_Hash.clear();
}
```

Note that the above technique would not work if the key of the hash table was a pointer (e.g. `QHash<QString*, QVariant>`).

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/containers.html#the-foreach-keyword) does not explicitly mention it, but it is a problem that you are mutating the container you are iterating over.

The code to `foreach` is [here](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/corelib/global/qglobal.h#line2371).

Looking at the code, it and your code do basically the same as if you'd write:

```
for (QHash::iterator it=m_Hash.begin(), end=m_Hash.end(); 
     it!=end;
     ++it)
{
    delete m_Hash.take(key);
}
```

however, the [`take`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qhash.html#take) member function may trigger an invalidation of existing iterators (`it` and `end`), so your iterators might have become dangling, yielding undefined behavior.

Possible solutions:
* do not modify the container you iterator over *while* iterating
* make sure `it` is valid before the next iteration begins, and don't store an `end`-iterator (this solution forbids the use of `foreach`)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is problem with the foreach keyword. Try replacing:

```
foreach( QString key, m_Hash.keys() )
{
    qDebug() << "Deleting an entry..";
    delete m_Hash.take(key);  // take changes the m_Hash object
}
```

with:

```
for (QHash<QString, QVariant*>::iterator it =  m_Hash.begin();
                                         it != m_Hash.end(); ++it)
{
    qDebug() << "Deleting an entry..";
    delete it.value();      // we delete only what it.value() points to, but the 
                            // m_Hash object remains intact.
}
m_Hash.clear();
```

This way the hash table remains unchanged while you iterate through it. It is possible that the foreach macro expands into a construct where you "delete the hashtable from under your feet". That is the macro probably creates an iterator, which becomes invalid or "dangling" as a side effect of calling

```
m_Hash.take(key);
```